# How to extract from the list of dictionary by checking latest timestamp and value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

There is a list of dictionaries below like

```
my_dictionary = [
  {
    'name': 'Tester',
    'id': '101',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  },
  {
    'name': 'Developer',
    'id': '102',
    'status': 'Success',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302',
  },
  {
    'name': 'Tester',
    'id': '101',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:013302'  }
]
```

- I have two `name` values as `Tester` or `Developer`
- By checking latest `lastModifiedDate` need to extract latest entry for `Tester`, `Developer`

Logic implemented in the below code is as follows:

- First sort the on the basis of `lastModifiedDate` in descending order.
- Extract the first occurrence in the list of dictionaries.

```
response = sorted(my_dictionary, key=lambda x: x['lastModifiedDate'], reverse=True)

response_latest = []
for item in response:
    extracted_response = {}
    for field in item:     
        if item['name'] == 'Tester':
            extracted_response[field] = item[field]
    response_latest.append(extracted_response)
    break
    for field in item:     
        if item['name'] == 'Developer':
            extracted_response[field] = item[field]
    response_latest.append(extracted_response)
    break
response_latest
```

The output of the above code on input as the above list of the dictionaries is

```
[{'name': 'Tester',
  'id': '101',
  'status': 'Failed',
  'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:013302'}]
```

but the expected output is

```
[{'name': 'Tester',
  'id': '101',
  'status': 'Failed',
  'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:013302'},
 {'name': 'Developer',
  'id': '102',
  'status': 'Success',
  'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'}]
```

Also, code should not fail in case of the absence of `Developer` or `Tester` dictionary name values.

```
my_dictionary = [{'name': 'Tester', 'id': '101', 'status': 'Failed', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'}, 
{'name': 'Tester', 'id': '101', 'status': 'Failed', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:013302'}]
```

Comment: What's the deal with the `break` statement that aborts your loop after the first item has been appended to `response_latest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried filtering `myd` and then finding the latest of each one.

```py
tester = list(filter(lambda x: x["name"] == "Tester", myd))
developer = list(filter(lambda x: x["name"] == "Developer", myd))

tester_latest = sorted(tester, key=lambda x: x["lastModifiedDate"], reverse=True)
developer_lastest = sorted(developer, key=lambda x: x["lastModifiedDate"], reverse=True)

response_latest = [
    tester_latest[0] if len(tester_latest) > 0 else None,
    developer_lastest[0] if len(developer_lastest) > 0 else None
]
response_latest = list(filter(None, response_latest)
response_latest
```

Comment: This answer will fetch one record per developer. My answer might fetch multiple records per developer in case the maximum timestamp appears more than once (in a group). OP didn't specify what is desired, so I guess both is OK.

Comment: @timgeb, is it required to first write into list then sort then write back to another list, is this correct approach of taking one extra space. upvoting for fast reply

Comment: Also code  will fails like myd = [
  {
    'name': 'Tester',
    'id': '101',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'  },
  {
    'name': 'Tester',
    'id': '101',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:013302'  }
] . If myd does not contain Developer' dictionary

Comment: Sorry, didn't expect the case that `myd` does not contain Developer. However, I fixed it by inserting `None` in this case and then filtering the output list.

Answer (score 1):

If `pandas` is in play:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(myd)
maxes = df.groupby('name')['lastModifiedDate'].transform('max')
result = df[df['lastModifiedDate'] == maxes].to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
>>> result
[{'name': 'Developer', 'id': '102', 'status': 'Success', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'}, {'name': 'Tester', 'id': '101', 'status': 'Failed', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:013302'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the method of converting a list of dictionaries to a pandas data frame and perform a few actions on it.

This example includes two `Tester` dictionaries having the same `lastModifiedDate` but having different `lastModifiedDate` in the case of `Developer`

```
my_dictionary_list = [
  {
    'name': 'Tester',
    'id': '101',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'},
  {
    'name': 'Developer',
    'id': '102',
    'status': 'Success',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:129405'},
  {
    'name': 'Tester',
    'id': '103',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'},
  {
    'name': 'Developer',
    'id': '102',
    'status': 'Success',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:113215'},
  {
    'name': 'Tester',
    'id': '103',
    'status': 'Failed',
    'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-12 12:25:32:013302'},
]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dictionary_list)
maxes_by_group = df.groupby(['name'])['lastModifiedDate'].transform(max)
print("maxes_by_group output - \n{}".format(maxes_by_group))
result = df[df['lastModifiedDate'] == maxes_by_group].to_dict(orient='records')
print("--------------------")
print("Final result output - \n{}".format(result))
```

Output -

```
maxes_by_group output - 
0    2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302
1    2022-02-21 12:25:32:113215
2    2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302
3    2022-02-21 12:25:32:113215
4    2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302
Name: lastModifiedDate, dtype: object
--------------------
Final result output - 
[{'name': 'Tester', 'id': '101', 'status': 'Failed', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'}, {'name': 'Tester', 'id': '103', 'status': 'Failed', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-14 12:25:32:013302'}, {'name': 'Developer', 'id': '102', 'status': 'Success', 'lastModifiedDate': '2022-02-21 12:25:32:113215'}]
```

`maxes_by_group` variable output represents descending order sorting of `lastModifiedDate` values.

You can see three dictionaries in the final `result` variable output. Two `Tester` name values are having the same maximum `lastModifiedDate` values and one `Developer` name value is having the maximum `lastModifiedDate` value.